# Google Sheets with Import XML - get name data from this website

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to import the following info from this page into a Google Sheet:
https://www.seditionart.com/artists/date/desc/curated

-Names of all the artists

-Link to each artist page

I've tried a number of variations on:

```
=importxmL("https://www.seditionart.com/artists/date/desc/curated", "//a/@href")
```

for links to their artist page, and

```
=importxmL("https://www.seditionart.com/artists/date/desc/curated", "//img[@alt")
```

for the image alt text to get their names.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. New to this. Thanks.

Comment: site is full JS therefore by normal means its not possible to scrape it into google sheets

Comment: Thanks, any workarounds?